# Using find to only step through symbolic links n times?

Tags: find, symlink

Is it possible to use `find` to recursively search a path but to only step through into a path which is symbolic link to a specified depth of `n`?

There is `-maxdepth` but this includes regular directories while I only want to limit the symbolic link depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the line of:

```
$ find -L -maxdepth n -path "/my/path/pattern" -xtype l -print
```

**Short explanation:**
- This should only print symbolic links to the specified depth, n, where n is a positive integer. 
- Options must precede arguments. This means that the order in which the cmd above is written matters. Anyway, `bash` will complain otherwise.  
- `-print` is the default so you can omit it in this case.

According to the `man` page on bash v4.4.12, the magic happens owing to:

> -xtype c 
>    The same as -type unless the file is a symbolic link.  For symbolic links: if the  -H  or -P option was specified, true if the
>   file is a link to a file of type c; if the -L option has been given,
>   true if c is `l'.  In other words, for symbolic links, -xtype checks 
>   the type of the file that -type does not check.

This works for me.